# spark error RDD type not found when creating RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create an RDD of case class objects.  Eg.,

```
// sqlContext from the previous example is used in this example.
// createSchemaRDD is used to implicitly convert an RDD to a SchemaRDD.
import sqlContext.createSchemaRDD

val people: RDD[Person] = ... // An RDD of case class objects, from the previous example.

// The RDD is implicitly converted to a SchemaRDD by createSchemaRDD, allowing it to be stored using        Parquet.
people.saveAsParquetFile("people.parquet")
```

I am trying to complete the part from the previous example by giving

```
    case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

    // Create an RDD of Person objects and register it as a table.
    val people: RDD[Person] = sc.textFile("/user/root/people.txt").map(_.split(",")).map(p => Person(p(0), p(1).trim.toInt))
    people.registerAsTable("people")
```

I get the following error:

```
<console>:28: error: not found: type RDD
       val people: RDD[Person] =sc.textFile("/user/root/people.txt").map(_.split(",")).map(p => Person(p(0), p(1).trim.toInt))
```

Any idea on what went wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The issue here is the explicit `RDD[String]` type annotation.  It looks like `RDD` isn't imported by default in `spark-shell`, which is why Scala is complaining that it can't find the `RDD` type.  Try running `import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD` first.